# Stack of a stack c#

Tags: c#, stack

So I have a stack of a few stacks.

This is how I implemented the stack: `public Stack<Stack<Baggage>> Trunk;`

So trunk is supposed to hold multiple stacks of baggage (one baggage stack has a limited number of bags it can hold)

The question I have is, how would I write out the trunk stack.

Ive tried using the pop() function but on the console it writes out this: `System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[TestDummy.Baggage]` I tried making an override ToString method in the baggage class but it doesn't work.

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood, you are trying to print `Trunk` content to console. You must keep in mind that inside your `Trunk` stack there are another stacks, so you should pop a value from that stack too, to get it

Here is a simple example code:

```
foreach(var baggage in Trunk.Pop())
{
    Console.WriteLine(baggage.Name);
}
```

`Trunk.Pop()` will take off stack from `Trunk` and `foreach` loop will iterate through elements of that stack and perform some action

Comment: yes, I figured it out now. What I did was set up a temp stack like this                 Stack<baggage> temp = Trunk.first(); And then went through that stack with a foreach loop